# Right circular loop

Tags: c++, cycle

I have to cycle from 0 to 5 with step 0.5. But the cycle should be reversed when the value is 5.

```
bool forward = true;
int counter = 0;
float val = 5.0f;

// And somewhere in global app cycle:
if (val <= 0.0 && forward) forward = false;
if (forward) val -= .5f;

if (val >= 5.0 && !forward) forward = true;
if (!forward) val += .5f;
```

But the result is sometimes negative numbers and, I think, that's a bit ugly code.

```
0.2
0.18
0.16
0.14
0.12
0.1
0.08
0.06
0.04
0.02
2.98023e-08
-0.02
2.98023e-08
0.02
0.04
0.06
0.08
0.1
0.12
0.14
0.16
0.18
0.2
0.2
0.18
```

Comment: What do you mean "the result is sometimes negative numbers"?  Please give an example of what you are observing.

Comment: @oli-charlesworth look at update, please. There is `-0.02` and `2.98023e-08`

Comment: I don't understand how this relates to your code.  For instance, why is the first value 0.2?

Comment: |val - 5.0| < eps   && |val - 0 | < eps   where | | in your case fabsf() i guess

Comment: @oli-charlesworth oh sorry, I posted result for 0; 0.2 with step 0.02.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is that `0.2` cannot be exactly represented in floating-point.  So when you write `val -= 0.2`, what you're really doing is `val -= 0.20000000298023224;`.  Therefore, you accumulate errors.

The solution is to not use floating-point to control your loop.  Use an `int` instead, and multiply by a constant to get `val`.  e.g.:

```
int inc = -1;
int i = 10;

while (whatever)
{
    if (i == 0) inc = +1;
    if (i == 10) inc = -1;

    i += inc;

    float val = i * 0.02;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use integers for such cycles from 0 to 10 with step 1 or from 0 to 50 with step 5. Float may be 0.00000012 and so it is not less or equal than 0.0.
You can calculate the float from your cycle variable when needed.

Answer (score 0):

|val - 5.0| < eps && |val - 0 | < eps where | | in your case fabsf() i guess

also keep in mind that there is some loss in precision whenever two almost equal (floating point representation) values are subtracted.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying the distance to move each time, could the number of divisions be specified?
This way, your value won't ever drift due to precision/rounding errors
EG:

```
void Step(float from, float to, int divisions)
{
    float range = to - from;
    float perDivision = range / divisions;

    int i = 0;
    for(;;)
    {
        for(; i < divisions; ++i)
        {
           UseCurrentValue(from + (i * perDivision));
        }
        for(; i > 0; --i)
        {
           UseCurrentValue(from + (i * perDivision));
        }
    }
}

void UseCurrentValue(float val)
{
   // Do something with val here.
}
```